# Add several cookies in IHTTPResponse

Tags: c#, cookies

How to add several cookies in IHTTPResponse by using AddHeaders method?

```
resp.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", "user=\"mary\"");
resp.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", "city=\"chicago\"");
```

The AddHeader overrides the previous headers, so I cannot have more than one cookie. Is there a way to add several cookies using IHTTPResponse interface? The second cookie overrides the first one. I cannot have more than one cookie.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Cookies collection like this:

```
HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("user", "mary");
HttpCookie cityCookie = new HttpCookie("city", "chicago");
resp.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
resp.Cookies.Add(cityCookie);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to use ResponseCookie in C# but it works perfectly! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `AddHeader` calls should not overwrite the header information, but I would try to change my calls to [`AppendHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as

> AddHeader is provided for compatibility with earlier versions of ASP.

But as DavidG has already suggested, use the Cookies collection instead.

Comment: I'm using C#. Only AddHeader is available. I cannot use AppendHeader. Thank you.